# Präpositionen und Kasus: Etymologie

Tags: preposition, etymology, grammatical-case

Gibt es eine, möglicherweise etymologische, Erklärung, warum einige Präpositionen (z.B. mit) immer Dativ und andere (z.B. ohne) immer Akkusativ regieren ?

Comment: Ich kann nichts spezifisch zum Deutschen beitragen, aber oft grammatikalisieren sich Präpositionen aus Nomen, die mit einem semantischen Fall kombiniert werden. Zb. finnisch _pöydän päällä_ "oben auf dem Tisch" -- wörtlich "Tisch.GEN Kopf.ALL", wobei der Allativ der "äußere statische Lokalkasus" ist.

Answer (score 3):

Das Problem, diese Frage zu beantworten, hängt damit zusammen, daß die Kasus im heutigen Deutsch das Resultat einer langen Entwicklung sind.

In der (rekonstruierten) indogermanischen Ursprache gab es 8 Fälle. Davon fielen im Laufe der Entwicklung immer mehr weg: Awestisch und Altindisch (die ältesten bekannten indogermanischen Sprache) hatten noch 8 Fälle, manche slawischen Sprachen 7; Latein hat 6 Fälle, wobei der 6. (Ablativ) eigentlich zwei Fälle vereint, den ursprünglichen Ablativ und den Instrumental (Casus instrumentalis). Ebenso haben andere slawische Sprachen (inklusive Russisch) 6 Fälle.

Deutsch hat als eine der wenigen west-indogermanischen Sprachen noch 4 Fälle, während etwa Englisch, Französisch, Spanisch, Italienisch, etc.. nur noch einen (Nominal-)-Fall haben und bestenfalls Pronomen noch deklinieren. Die meisten Präpositionalfälle im Deutschen entstanden historisch dadurch, daß in der spätklassischen Periode, beim Übergang von einerseits Latein und andererseits germanischen Sprachen hin zu Deutsch, die Aussprache des Ablativs (langer vs. kurzer Suffixvokal) undeutlich wurde und die Leute zur besseren Unterscheidung Präpositionen (cum, sine, ...) gebrauchten, um das Gemeinte zu verdeutlichen.

Die Bildung der Präpositionalfälle bzw. die Zuordnung der Präpositionen zu einelnen Kasus folgt also keiner stringenten Gesetzmäßigkeit, sondern entstand "ad hoc", im Sprachgebrauch. Wie die meisten solcherart entstandenen Strukturen folgt das System zwar gewissen rudimentären Regeln, die aber für Ausnahmen eine Menge Spielraum lassen.

Comment: Die deutschen Präpositionalfälle sind also maßgeblich Analogiebildungen aus dem Lateinischen? Das halte ich durchaus nicht für unglaubhaft, aber hast du noch Referenzen dazu? Ich hätte nämlich vermutet, dass sie einfach direkt und eigenständig aus semantischem Kasusgebrauch abgeleitet werden können. Auch wenn ich nicht sagen könnte, wann.

Comment: Eine direkte belastbare Quelle habe ich im Internet nicht gefunden, allerdings zitiert wikipedia (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kasus#Das_Kasussystem_im_indogermanischen_Sprachraum) in Anmerkung 25 den Duden (Die Grammatik, 4. Aufl.) und belegt damit "An die Stelle eines Flexionskasus tritt ein Präpositionalkasus." Das sollte zumindest als weiterführender Hinweis reichen. Auch der Vergleich mit der finno-ugrischen Sprachfamilie legt diese These nahe. Diese Sprachen haben alle kaum Präpositionen, dafür aber wesentlich mehr Fälle als indogermanische Sprachen.

Comment: Soviel ist mir klar, ja. Aber du hast geschrieben, die Präpositionalfälle hätten sich gebildet "beim Übergang von einerseits Latein und andererseits germanischen Sprachen hin zu Deutsch". Ich lese das als: die lateinischen Kasus und Präpositionen hatten (auch) einen direkten Einfluss auf das Deutsche. War das nicht so gemeint? (Dass das Lateinische großen _syntaktischen_ Einfluss hatte, vor allem durch Lehnübersetzungen, ist ja bekannt -- ich habe nur noch nie von etwas Ähnlichem bei Fällen gehört.)

Answer (score 0):

*oh-n* klingt halt wie zu *de-n* gehörig; *mit-* dagegen eher wie *dit* (bzw. eher *dem*). Also, *mit dem Instrument* ist offens instrumental. Dieser Fall ist nach dem Urgermanischen halt mittels dem Dativ vereinfacht worden. Vermutlich,ist *hal-t* noch ein Hinweis darauf, da dieses Wort sonst keinen bedeutenden Sinn zu haben scheint als den Dativus Instrumentalis zu bilden. Das verdeutlicht sich ferner, da wo *Mittel* anscheinend mit dem "tool-suffiix" *dhlom gebildet wurde. Abschließend geklärt ist das aber scheinbar aber nicht.

Comment: Diese Antwort ist für mich zum großen Teil unverständlich.

Comment: @Jonathen.Scholbach, dit liegt sicherlich daran, dass du gar nicht erst versucht hast, valide Kritik zu formulieren. Manchmal sollt's ja helfen, einfach mal darüber zu reden, quasi im Sinne von Gesprächstherapie. Gut, vielleicht wurde der Versuch unternommen und im Ansatz für albern befunden. Wie lange ist das wohl schon her? Falls schon die Einleitung verwirrt, *oh-n* / *de-n* soll "agreement" darstellen. Wie das zu Deutsch genannt wird, das weiß ich tatsächlich nicht, denn es steht gar nicht in Frage.

Comment: Ich habe bereits die Probleme, die Kohärenz des Textes zu erfassen. Was ist "offens"? Was ist _hal-t_? Und worauf ist es ein Hinweis? Inwiefern ist _Mittel_ mit dem "tool-suffiix" *dhlom gebildet? Und wieso "anscheinend"? Entweder der Text ist voller Voraussetzungen, von denen ich meine würde, dass man sie nennen sollte, oder er ist einfach konfus. Ich kann das nicht beurteilen, weil ich es wirklich nicht verstehe.

Comment: _Falls schon die Einleitung verwirrt, oh-n / de-n soll "agreement" darstellen._ - das verstehe ich übrigens auch nicht :)

Comment: Der Binde-Strich ist eine äußert übliche Zeichensetzung zur Ab-grenz-ung von Wortteilen voneinander, in diesem Fall vermutlich der Endung. Endungen der am Satzbau beteiligten Teile einer Wortgruppe stimmen häufig überein, manchmal nur zufällig, manches mal gar nicht, früher wohl mehr im Kasus als heut. Wenn die Endungen von einem Kasus "regiert" werden, spricht man von "agreement". Bzw. kann es auch entgegengesetzt verlaufen, wenn man glauben möchte, der Kasus regiere, dann setzt man die Endung. Bspw. *einen schönen Wagen*, *eines schönen Tages*, *wegen den Mannen*, etc.

Comment: Daher ebenso *ohne'n Funken Hoffnung*, *ohn' Fleiß kein Preis*, wobei zu vermuten steht dass *Funken* überhaupt nur gesetzt wurde, damit *'n* aus *-n* > *ne'n* als unbestimmter Artikel interpretiert werden kann, während das *-e* als Fugenlaut entstanden sein könnte, vgl. *ohn' Erbarm'*, *(un-)erbärmlich*. Die Wurzel ist doch offens *un-* < \*n ~ \*ne "no", wie in *ne, nein, den wohl kaum*. *Offens.* ist eine schlechte angewohnheit, zumindest in juristischer Fachliteratur ausgezeichnet.

Comment: Bzw. ist angesichts der nebenstehend scheinbar oft positiven Bedeutung (*ohne Murren ohne Knurren*) das *-e vielleicht auch eigenständig gewesen, wie *je-*, Engl. *e-ver*, AGr. *ouke* "not", usw. So wär Akk. ggf. Tempus bezogen, vgl. *wann* auch in fiktiven Ortsangbaben, vgl. *Weltenlohn*, *Welt* < *wer-ald* "age of man"; English *whence*, angeblich *when* + *-s*; Lat. akkusativ *multos annos* "for many years", lativ *domum* "homewards", De. *gen Norden*; *jeden Dienstag*, *seit Tagen*, Engl. *yonder*, OE *ginster* "yesterday", aber genitivisch *dienstags*, *tagsüber*, nom. nunmehr *tag'über*.

Comment: ... treffende Beispiele fehlen allerdings. DWDS nennt "nicht ohne", "Zweifels ohne sein".